# Add array elements in an array position

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I add an array to array position:

Something like a:

```
<?php
$newArr = array('email' => array("id" => "5678", "token" => "fghjk"));
$arr = array(
        "auth"=>
            array(
                'users'=>
                    array(
                        'id' =>"456yhjoiu",
                        'token' => "asdfghjkrtyui678"
                    )
                )
            );

somefunction($arr['auth'], $newArr);
```

I've tried `array_push()` but it added zero (0) before 'email' instead.~

I'm doing this to get a json output, something like this:

```
}
    "auth": {
        "users": {
            "id": "456yhjoiu",
            "token": "asdfghjkrtyui678"
        },
        "email": {
             "id": "5678",
             "token": "fghjk"
        }
    }
}
```

but I have this output:

```
{
    "auth": {
        "users": {
            "id": "456yhjoiu",
            "token": "asdfghjkrtyui678"
        },
        "0": {
            "email": {
                "id": "5678",
                "token": "fghjk"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why put a negative point in my question?

Comment: What's wrong with `$arr['auth']['email'] = $newArr['email'];`?

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you actually try to do.

Comment: I'm trying to put $newArr into $arr['auth']

Comment: Or this, `$arr['auth'][key($newArr)] = $newArr[key($newArr)];`? P.S- Not my downvote, but I think the downvote is because this question is *too trivial*, or may be there's more to the story.

Comment: If you show an example of what you are trying to see it will help people understand your question better and prevent others from giving you downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = ['auth' => array_merge($arr['auth'], $newArr)];
```

or old array notation <= PHP5.3

```
$data = array('auth' => array_merge($arr['auth'], $newArr));
```